# Class Cast Exception problems with TreeSet

Tags: java

Ok, I have this problem to solve:

Create a generic class called `VirtualLibrary` with a single attribute, `totalNumberOfEntries`, and with methods which enables the user to set and return an entry. The types of entries are `Book`, `Article`, `MediaResource`, `Magazine` and `Manual`. Implement the specific classes for each type of entry. 
In the `main( )` method create a `SortedSet<VirtualLibrary>` variable which maintains all the library entries. Use the methods to add, add multiple, return a specific entry and check if an entry exists in the library.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class VirtualLibrary<T>{
    private int totalNumberOfEntries;
    void setTotalNumberOfEntries(int totalNumberOfEntries) {
        this.totalNumberOfEntries=totalNumberOfEntries;
    }
    int getTotalNumberOfEntries() {
        return this.totalNumberOfEntries;
    }
}
class Base{}
class Book extends Base{
}
class Article extends Base{ 
}
class MediaResource extends Base{
}
class Magazine extends Base{
}
class Manual extends Base{
}

public class P5 {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VirtualLibrary<Book> book = new VirtualLibrary<>();
        SortedSet<VirtualLibrary> lib = new TreeSet<>();
        int totalNumberOfEntries;
        System.out.println("Please insert the total number of entries of the book: ");
        totalNumberOfEntries=keyboard.nextInt();
        book.setTotalNumberOfEntries(totalNumberOfEntries);
        lib.add(book);
        VirtualLibrary<Article> article = new VirtualLibrary<>();
        System.out.println("Please insert the total number of entries of the article: ");
        totalNumberOfEntries=keyboard.nextInt();
        article.setTotalNumberOfEntries(totalNumberOfEntries);
        VirtualLibrary<MediaResource> mediaResource = new VirtualLibrary<>();
        System.out.println("Please insert the total number of entries of the media resource: ");
        totalNumberOfEntries=keyboard.nextInt();
        mediaResource.setTotalNumberOfEntries(totalNumberOfEntries);
        VirtualLibrary<Magazine> magazine = new VirtualLibrary<>();
        System.out.println("Please insert the total number of entries of the magazine: ");
        totalNumberOfEntries=keyboard.nextInt();
        magazine.setTotalNumberOfEntries(totalNumberOfEntries);
        VirtualLibrary<Manual> manual = new VirtualLibrary<>();
        System.out.println("Please insert the total number of entries of the manual: ");
        totalNumberOfEntries=keyboard.nextInt();
        manual.setTotalNumberOfEntries(totalNumberOfEntries);
        Collections.addAll(lib, article,mediaResource,magazine,manual);
        System.out.println(lib.first());
        System.out.println(lib.last());
        System.out.println(lib);

    }

}
```

I cant figure it out.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class VirtualLibrary cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (VirtualLibrary is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1291)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:536)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at P5.main(P5.java:50)
```

Comment: `VirtualLibrary` does not implement `Comparable`, so why would you think you can cast it willy-nilly?

Comment: `VirtualLibrary` doesn't implement `Comparable`. It cannot be used as element type of a `TreeSet` (unless you provide a `Comparator` in the constructor).

Comment: Any ideas how can I use getClass() to show book, article etc? Now I get VirtualLibrary for everything.

Comment: @MauricePerry just override `toString()` in all classes and print the set.

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel if i understand you correctly, `toString()` must also be overriden to get anything meaningful when the set is printed?

Comment: Yes, set `toString` is already overridden, it will print each element, you just need to override element `toString`

Comment: I did for all classes and still shows VirtualLibrary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TreeSet` sorts data inserted in it. By default it doesn't know how to sort java classes.

So, either you need to provide a `Comparator` in constructor or the class you are using with `TreeSet` should implement `Comparable`.

```
// using comparator
SortedSet<ClassA> set = new TreeSet<>( new Comparator() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ClassA a, ClassA b) {
        // your implementation 
    }
});

// java 8 lambda
SortedSet<ClassA> set = new TreeSet<>( (a, b) -> {
   // your implementation
});
```

Or

```
class ClassA implements Comparable<ClassA> {

    ....
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ClassA other) {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas how can I use getClass() to show book, article etc? Now I get VirtualLibrary for everything.

Comment: @Override
 public String toString() {
  return this.getClass()+" "+this.getTotalNumberOfEntries();
 }

Comment: I receive only virtual class