# Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException whenever I use treeset .add() method in java

Tags: java, collections, treeset

So I have this assignment which I need to put data into a tree set. I have three classes they are :

1. Brother.java. The assignment said the constructor is not public, so I'm using the getInstance() to initialize Brother object

   ```
   public class Brother {
   String name;
   int day;
   int month;
   private static Brother instance = null;

   private Brother()
   {
       name = "0";
       day = 0;
       month = 0;
   }

   public static Brother getInstance()
   {
       if(instance == null)
       {
           instance = new Brother();
       }
       return instance;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Family class. This class is used to assign the brother object into the tree set with Brother as the objects.

   ```
   import java.util.Set;
   import java.util.TreeSet;    
   public class Family {
   Set<Brother> Brothers;

   public Family()
   {
       this.Brothers = new TreeSet<Brother>(); 
   }

   public Brother makeBrother()
   {
       Brother B = Brother.getInstance();
       return B;
   }

   public boolean addBrother(String name, int day, int month)
   {
       Brother B = Brother.getInstance(); 
       return Brothers.add(B);
   }
   }
   ```
3. And finally the main class

   ```
       public class Main {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
           Family myFamily = new Family();

           myFamily.makeBrother();
           // myFamily.addBrother("Shane", 3, 2);
       }
   }
   ```

whenever I try to use myFamily.addBrother() I always got this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Brother cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (Brother is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')". What do I have to do with that? The program is perfectly fine when I use myFamily.makeBrother(). This algorithm is not all done yet but when I try to run it this happened to me and I cannot continue to the next step. Thank you before.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Set instead of a List because you want to avoid duplicates. To know which Brothers are duplicate, a TreeSet needs either a comparator, or the objects themselves need to implement Comparable.

Read the javadoc of TreeSet for more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

BTW that getInstance always returns the same instance. You'll probably need to change that to createInstance or something that actually creates new ones.

Comment: hello thank you for answering. I already change the getInstance() so it wont return the same instance but the error is still the same.I still lost in "a TreeSet needs either a comparator, or the objects themselves need to implement Comparable." because I think all I have to write is add(E e) and I'm following that but again, still have the same error

Comment: A `HashSet` wouldn't care about `Comparable` or `Comparator` (it operates off of `hashCode`)... but `TreeSet` does because it is a `SortedSet`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @GreyFairer, you have to provide a comparator in order to use Set, see this example:

[Class Cast Exception problems with TreeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745743/class-cast-exception-problems-with-treeset)

I hope it can helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems there.

1. You have defined `Brother` as a singleton. That means only one `Brother` instance will exist in your program. So all references to `Brother` will point to the same instace. I would avoid singleton for this class since doesn't makes sense.
2. If you what to use a `TreeSet` (without providing a Comparator for the Tree) then `Brother` must implement `Comparable`
3. `Family.makeBrother` just return the singleton `Brother`, but does not add it to the family tree, that's why you don't get the error.

This is a working rework of your code

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class FamilyTreeSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Family myFamily = new Family();

        myFamily.addBrother("Shane", 3, 2);
        myFamily.addBrother("Bob", 2, 4);

        System.out.println(myFamily);
    }

    public static class Brother implements Comparable<Brother>{
        private String name;
        private int day;
        private int month;

        public Brother(String name, int day, int month) {
            this.name = name;
            this.day = day;
            this.month = month;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getDay() {
            return day;
        }

        public int getMonth() {
            return month;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Brother o) {
            return Comparator.comparing(Brother::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).compare(this, o);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Brother{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", day=" + day +
                    ", month=" + month +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static class Family {
        Set<Brother> Brothers;

        public Family()
        {
            this.Brothers = new TreeSet<Brother>();
        }

        public boolean addBrother(String name, int day, int month)
        {
            Brother B = new Brother(name, day, month);
            return Brothers.add(B);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Family{" +
                    "Brothers=" + Brothers +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the each brother's name to compare brothers. Check that I first add Shane but in the output Bob goes first. If you want to compare brothers by birthday just change the compareTo.
`Family{Brothers=[Brother{name='Bod', day=2, month=4}, Brother{name='Shane', day=3, month=2}]}`